# Hide element (Ionic React ts)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I have

```
const Dashboard: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ history }) => {

  var random = 1;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <IonTitle id="title">MyLittleClass Dashboard</IonTitle>
      <IonContent>
      </IonContent>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

How can I hide the element with id "title" if my var random is 1??
.... its simple, but I dont understand how I can reference my element.

Ty

Answer (score 0):

use conditional display like:

```
const Dashboard: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ history }) => {

  var random = 1;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {random === 1 && <IonTitle id="title">MyLittleClass Dashboard</IonTitle>}
      <IonContent>
      </IonContent>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

in that case `IonTitle` will be rendered only in case when `random` will be equal number 1.